# Node.js - Unable to load from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sdk

Using a JS sdk of Icon a blockchain. Trying to using the SDK API calls and I'm having issues *import* or *require*

When I use **Import** an error is thrown **SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**
When I use **require** an error is thrown  **ReferenceError: HttpProvider is not defined**

Below is the link to Icon Icx Github
[Icon GitHub](https://github.com/icon-project/icon-sdk-js#installation)

```
const IconService = require('icon-sdk-js');
//import IconService from 'icon-sdk-js';

const provider = new HttpProvider('https://bicon.net.solidwallet.io/api/v3');

const iconService = new IconService(provider);

const totalSupply = iconService.getTotalSupply().execute();

console.log(totalSupply);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS you use require to "import" node modules and dependencies to your project

`const IconService = require('icon-sdk-js');`

Regarding this line `const provider = new HttpProvider('https://bicon.net.solidwallet.io/api/v3');`

Where are you importing `HttpProvider` from? `HttpProvider` is not built in Javascript library.

If it is a node module, you have to do something similar

`const HttpProvider = require('HttpProvider');` (in your question you don't specify what `HttpProvider` is)

Comment: HttpProvider is a class representing HTTP-based provider. It is commonly used for setting provider url of IconService instance.

Comment: In that case `const provider = IconService .HttpProvider('https://bicon.net.solidwallet.io/api/v3');` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think you might use `IconService.HttpProvider('the url');` to use the constructor